# Case Insensitive sort in mongodb without using aggregation framework(cursor.sort())

Tags: mongodb

I want to sort the data (case Insensitve) in mongodb without using aggregation-framework

```
db.orders.find().sort( { name: -1 } )
```

Something like `caseInsensitive : true`
Thanks

Comment: Wait until next stable release, it is all there

Comment: @Sammaye : So there is nothing for case Insensitive sort for now??

Comment: No, this has been a long standing task, along with collations, both of which are solved